# Split does not separate with tokens

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this string defined

```
const str : string = 'hostel:uk>london>city>street';
```

that I want to split to see only hostel, but I see the whole string in the console

```
console.log(str.split([":"][1]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the first part until colon.

```js
const
    str = 'hostel:uk>london>city>street',
    first = str.match(/^[^:]+/)[0];

console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `[]` after the `split()` as the output of a `split()` is an array.

So your code will change to,

```
console.log(str.split([":"])[0]);
```

Also, after the `split()`, "hostel" will be at the 0th index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select item **0**, and also do that after the split call (not inside it), and you need to pass a string into split:

```
console.log(str.split(":")[0]);
```

Comment: Indeed, in javascript it actually works (who knew) but typescript is rightfully strict about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform your desired output after adding this line

```
console.log(str.split(':')[0]);
```